# finding hourly difference between database timestamp and current time

Tags: php

I am trying to get the difference between database time and current time but I'm experiencing an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function diff() on string in E:\system\xamp\htdocs\project\signup\signup.php:133 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
```

Below is the code I am using

```
$query = "select DISTINCT `time` from `sing/login`";
$sql = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $time= $data['time'];

    date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Nairobi');
    $now= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
   
    echo "todays date" . $now;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "database time" . $time;
    $difference=$time->diff($now);
    $hours = $diff->h;
}
```

Comment: `$time` is a string, not an object. Did you mean to create a [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object from it?

Comment: I was using it to store the date i fetched from the database

Comment: Right. It's coming back from the database as a string. Just like the error message is telling you. It's a string that has the textual representation of a date, but it's not a date object.

Comment: how do i change it to a date object

Comment: By following examples on the PHP documentation page that I linked to above.

Comment: why not do it in the sql query? Also - you don't do anything with the result `$hours = $diff->h;`

Comment: i have converted the string to date using strtotime function  but am unable to get the difference as it gives me long numbers  when i convert to date